# why count(*) is slow even with index?

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle12c, sql-execution-plan, sql-tuning

This is my query:

```
   select count(*)
    FROM TB_E2V_DOCUMENTOS_CICLO D
    WHERE (D.TIPOCLIENTE = null or null is null)
      AND (D.TIPODOCUMENTOCLIENTE = null or null is null)
      AND (D.NUMDOCUMENTOCLIENTE = null or null is null)
      AND (D.BA = null or null is null)
      AND (D.FA = null or null is null)
      AND (D.NOMBRECLIENTE = null or null is null)
      AND (D.NUMTELEFONO = null or null is null)
      AND (D.NUMSUSCRIPCION = null or null is null)
      AND (D.TIPORECIBO in ('Recibo'))
      AND (D.NUMRECIBO = null or null is null)
      AND (TO_DATE(D.FECHAEMISION, 'yyyy/MM/dd') BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-5-1', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND TO_DATE('2020-2-18', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
      AND (D.MONTORECIBO = null or null is null)
      AND (D.NUMPAGINAS = 0 or 0 = 0)
      AND (D.NOMBREARCHIVO = null or null is null)
      AND (D.NEGOCIO = null or null is null)
      AND (D.NOMBREMETADATACARGA = null or null is null)
      AND (D.FECHACARGA = TO_DATE(null) or TO_DATE(null) is null);
```

This query returns
[image: result]

And when I do a Xplain For:

[image]

The cost is very high, but this query uses the index. The query lasts 10 seconds approximately.
How can I improve the performance of the query?

I'm using Oracle 12c

Comment: One thing that's slowing things down might be that `FECHAEMISION` apparently is of a string type, not a date type. All the `= null` don't make sense, they never gonna be true but maybe the optimizer deletes that. Same for the `OR NULL IS NULL` or `OR 0 = 0` parts. They make the sub condition true no matter what, so you can delete the respective conditions all together. But once again the optimizer hopefully does that itself.

Comment: I'm guessing that this query normally has bind variables, and you've replaced them with `null` for testing?

Comment: Removing all the unnecessary stuff, as I explained in the other comment, the `WHERE` clause is reduced to `D.TIPORECIBO = 'Recibo' AND TO_DATE(D.FECHAEMISION, 'yyyy/MM/dd') BETWEEN TO_DATE('2019-5-1', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND TO_DATE('2020-2-18', 'yyyy-MM-dd')`. Does the index index `TIPORECIBO` and then `TO_DATE(D.FECHAEMISION, 'yyyy/MM/dd')` (you might be able to use an FBI here to compensate the poor schema design)? If not, what does it index?

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: how many unique value D.TIPORECIBO has?

Answer (score 0):

Notes:  All of the " and ( = null or null is null)" predicates will always evaluate to true; Oracle does not define null so null does not equal null, so instead if you want to check for null then use "is null"

```
select * from dual where null = null; -- returns no rows
select * from dual where not (null <> null); -- returns no rows
select * from dual where null is null;  -- returns 1 row
select * from dual where not(null is not null);  -- returns 1 row
```

As far as indexing goes, you need an index that is selective (i.e. return much fewer rows) and is present in the where clause predicate.  In this case it looks like a function-based index on TO_DATE(D.FECHAEMISION, 'yyyy/MM/dd')
along with D.TIPORECIBO is in order.  The INDEX SKIP SCAN is used in this case probably because D.TIPORECIBO is not the leading column; INDEX SKIP SCANs are slower then INDEX RANGE SCANs because it needs to read more index blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few factors involved here:

First, this query is using the second (or third) part of a composite index, resulting in the `SKIP SCAN`.

Take a look at all indexes on the table and see what kind of index is on `TIPORECIBO`.
It is likely that this isn't the leading column. You might improve the performance by creating an index with `TIPORECIBO` as leading column, but it is unlikely--this appears to be a "type" column that might have only a few values, and not a good candidate for an index.

The second issue is that Oracle uses the index to get a set of candidate rows, then goes to the data blocks themselves to get the rows for further filtering.
A `select count(*)` will perform much better if Oracle doesn't need to fetch the data blocks. This can be achieved by creating an index that contains all of the data needed for the filter.

In your case, an index on `TIPORECIBO` and `FECHAEMISION` would mean that Oracle could go to the index alone without needing to access the data blocks.

The third issue is that you are applying `TO_DATE` to the `FECHAEMISION` column. If this is a `DATE` datatype, then you don't need the conversion and it is causing you trouble. If you do need the conversion, an option would be a function-based index on `TO_DATE(D.FECHAEMISION, 'yyyy/MM/dd')`.

To tune this particular query, you can try a function-based composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX TB_E2V_DOCUMENTOS_CICLO_FX1 ON TB_E2V_DOCUMENTOS_CICLO(FECHAEMISION, TO_DATE(D.FECHAEMISION, 'yyyy/MM/dd'))
```

Finally, this query is clearly being generated from code:
lines like `AND (D.BA = null or null is null)` seem to be a way of excluding portions of the `WHERE` clause when the front-end passes a `NULL`. This would possibly be `AND (D.BA = 'X' or 'X' is null)` if a value were provided for that parameter.

As such, be careful when tuning for the current set of parameters, as any change in what generated this query will impact the effectiveness of your tuning.

If you have a way to influence how this query is generated, it would be nice to simply exclude those non-event filters when the values are not provided, though Oracle ought to be able to handle them as-is.